# Nested struct conversion from mgo (mongodb library) to golang struct?

Tags: go, mgo

I have a struct like this:

```
type ArticleDocument struct {
    ArticleID    string `json:"article_id" bson:"article_id"`
    ArticleTitle string `json:"article_title" bson:"article_title"`
    Author       string `json:"author" bson:"author"`
    Board        string `json:"board" bson:"board"`
    Content      string `json:"content" bson:"content"`
    Date         string `json:"date" bson:"date"`
    IP           string `json:"ip" bson:"ip"`
    MessageConut struct {
        All     int `json:"all" bson:"all"`
        Boo     int `json:"boo" bson:"boo"`
        Count   int `json:"count" bson:"count"`
        Neutral int `json:"neutral" bson:"neutral"`
        Push    int `json:"push" bson:"push"`
    } `json:"message_count,inline" bson:"message_count,inline"`
    Messages []interface{} `json:"messages" bson:"messages"`
    URL      string        `json:"url" bson:"url"`
}
```

In MongoDB, my document looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab1da8133691b034b2be31d"),
    "article_id" : "M.1521548086.A.DCA",
    "article_title" : "some title",
    "author" : "somebody",
    "board" : "some board",
    "content" : "some content",
    "date" : "Tue Mar 20 20:14:42 2018",
    "ip" : "1.1.1.1",
    "message_conut" : {
        "all" : 15,
        "boo" : 0,
        "count" : 14,
        "neutral" : 1,
        "push" : 14
    },
    "messages" : [],
    "url" : "https://xxx.xxx.xxx"
}
```

In my Golang code, i am trying to use mgo to query this document and print it out, however, all document fields are converted to golang struct correctly except the nested document "MessageConut", all the values in "All", "Boo", "Count", ...etc are zero:

```
message_count":{"all":0,"boo":0,"count":0,"neutral":0,"push":0}"
```

Could you please guide how do I solve this issue?

Comment: You're using two different spellings of "count". The struct and MongoDB use "conut" but your tag says `bson:"message_count,inline"`. This will probably continue to cause problems until someone gets around to rebuilding your MongoDB collection to use the right spelling.

Comment: OMG.... it's ridiculous typo here, thank you and I will try again